# How can a div at the top of the page coexist with Adminstration Menu?

Tags: 7, routes, theming

I want to place the Page execution times at the top of the page. I first tried it in a block as mentioned [in this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/89957/can-the-devel-page-generation-times-be-placed-at-the-top-of-the-page), but the code for the block executes before the page is fully rendered, resulting in the wrong time.

Devel places the Page execution time is place in a div class `.dev-query` and I tried placing it at the top of the page.

The problem is it gets obscured by `Admin menu` and after reading a few solutions such as this one on [stackoverflow 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216114/how-can-i-make-a-div-stick-to-the-top-of-the-screen-once-its-been-scrolled-to) and [stackoverflow 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13274592/leave-menu-bar-fixed-on-top-when-scrolled) and I wonder if someone has `been there and done that` in relation with `Admin menu`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing that with the CSS is as below:

```
.dev-query {
    position: fixed;
    top: 33px;
    width: 100%;
    left: 30px;
    color: #000;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

I have tried that and it seems to be working for me.

---

Another way of doing this with the JS I have [mentioned here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/89957/can-the-devel-page-generation-times-be-placed-at-the-top-of-the-page) is somewhat like below:

```
<div id="page-execution-time-custom"></div>
<script>
(function ($) {
  // Jquery onload function.
  $(document).ready(function(){
    // Display the page execution time in the custom wrapper as below.
    var page_execution_time = $('.dev-query').text();
    $('#page-execution-time-custom').text(page_execution_time);
  });
})(jQuery); 
</script>
```